# IPython: How to wipe IPython's history selectively & securely?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have been learning how to use the `paramiko` package only to discover that all I stored passwords in plain text in IPython's `%hist`. Not so good.

I therefore need to get rid of particular parts of what is stored in `%hist`. Saying that, I do not want to wipe the *whole history*. - Only the parts where I have been careless enough to type `password =` or similar chosen terms.

*Thanks*

---

Comments I don't need:

- `%clear` only clears the session. It does not wipe the history.
- Yes. I will only use xSA_keys from now on.

Comment: Note that you can wipe the entire history with `ipython history clear` if you just want to remove everything.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

History is store on `$(ipython locate)/profile_default/history.sqlite` by default. 
You can remove the file, and or do any operation you want on it (secure erase, etc..). 
It's an sqlite file so you can load it with any sqlite program and do query on it.

Check in `$(ipython locate)/profile_default/` and other `$(ipython locate)/profile_xxx` that you do not have any other history files. `$(ipython locate)` is usually `~/.ipython/` but can vary:

```
ls $(ipython locate)/profile_*/*.sqlite
```

Comment: Hm, `$(ipython locate)` gives me `[TerminalIPythonApp] File not found: u'locate'`, but I'm able to locate it at `~/.ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite.`

Comment: For windows users: C:\Users\<user>\.ipython\profile_default\history.sqlite
In adition to that, if you dont have a sqlite client, i highly recomend a graphical utility called "DB Browser for SQLite"

Comment: Just to double-check: This history is local to the machine and isn't stored inside the notebook, right? I have a notebook from which I deleted solutions, if I share the notebook, the history containing the solutions will not be recoverable, correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

One solution would be:

```
sqlite ~/.ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite

delete from history where source like '%password =%';
```

Comment: If you do this, after you might want to delete the sqlite3 history in `~/.sqlite_history`.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to delete history from a particular session, run:

```
sqlite ~/.ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite
```

Note that on some systems, you will need to run `sqlite3` rather than `sqlite`.

Inside SQLite:

```
select * from history;
# session is the first column in history
delete from history where session=XXX;
```

Also, here is a SQLite query that will give you the id of your last session:

```
select session from history order by -session limit 1;
```

Answer (score 6):

Combining [@Ovidiu Ghinet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5277725/ovidiu-ghinet)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39047405/623735) with [@Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/137794/matt)'s [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19606820/623735):

```
sqlite $(ipython locate)/profile_*/*.sqlite || sqlite3 $(ipython locate)/profile_*/*.sqlite
```

Then from within sqlite console:

```
delete from history where source like '%password%';
select * from history; /* confirm that no passwords left        */
.quit                  /* forgot how to exit sqlite console? ;) */
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find the way to wipe IPython's history selectively, but I found out how to wipe data by built-in func, non-sqlite way:

**%clear out** #it clears output history

by the way, you can also clear in history by %clear in

Answer (score 0):

If you want completely from beginning, Just go and delete the following file manually(It worked for me)

/home/user/.ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite

Comment: this is not selective deletion, you lose all your goodies from you history.