# how can I avoid storing a command in ipython history?

Tags: python, ipython, history

In bash I can prevent a command from being saved to bash history by putting a space in front of it. I cannot use this method in ipython. How would I do the equivalent in ipython?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606275/ipython-how-to-wipe-ipythons-history-selectively-securely

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obsolescence note: this was written for `IPython 4.0.1`. [As of v5, IPython no longer uses `readline`](http://blog.jupyter.org/2016/07/08/ipython-5-0-released/).

---

No stock way, can be added in or worked around.

There are two kinds of history in IPython:

- `readline` history. It is available with special keys/key combinations (up/down, Ctrl-R etc). Only stores lines entered (with `<Enter>`) on the console (or, in `pyreadline`, pasted from the clipboard, too). IPython relies on a local implementation of the [Python `readline` API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html) which doesn't have a "do not add" function and normally adds every line to history.
  IPython has a facility to alleviate this, `IPython.core.interactiveshell.ReadlineNoRecord`, a context manager that makes a snapshot of history then restores it. As of `ipython 4.0.1`, it's only used by `%run` magic to avoid adding script interactive input to history.
- IPython history. It's saved in the DB and automatic variables. It contains complete inputs (`readline` grabs each `<Enter>`'ed line separately for multiline ones) and outputs. Saving is implemented in `HistoryManager.store_inputs()` (for inputs) and `HistoryManager.store_output()` (for outputs) which is called from `InteractiveShell.run_cell` and is governed by its `store_history` argument. The latter is in turn called from `TerminalInteractiveShell.interact` with `store_history=True`.

There are two ways to solve the problem for either layer:

- prevent adding the input in the first place. This cannot be done with a magic prefixed to a command, only with one that is run as a separate command and toggles a flag. That's because, as you've seen, the current input has already been stored by the time a magic command gets control.

  - readline: there's no relevant entry in the public API, so it's implementation-specific. E.g. for `pyreadline`, adding is done with `pyreadline.modes.basemode.BaseMode.add_history()`. The mode object is accessible as `get_ipython().readline.rl.mode`.
  - Decorating `run_cell` and `add_history` with wrappers checking flags in corresponding objects and a [custom magic command](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/config/custommagics.html) that sets/toggles them should do the trick.
- automatically remove <s>evidence</s> input/output from history immediately after execution. This can be done with a prefix magic.

  - IPython: `HistoryManager` doesn't have any facilities to remove entries (neither from DB nor from variables). Alas, hacking the DB by hand/replacing stock `HistoryManager` is necessary. Also note that the class has an optional cache of `HistoryManager.db_cache_size` (disabled by default).
  - readline: `remove_history_item(index)` is in the API. You need to know the number of lines in the input.

Alternatively, *if you only require this to enter passwords, consider other ways that don't echo the password on screen* (thus not making it a part of console history):

- [`getpass.getpass()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass)
- storing it elsewhere (like a configuration file only readable by you)

Comment: 1. _"prevent adding the input in the first place. This cannot be done with a magic prefixed to a command, only with one that is run as a separate command and toggles a flag"_ what is an example of a separate command toggling a flag to prevent adding the input?

2. _Decorating run_cell and add_history with wrappers checking flags in corresponding objects and a custom magic command that sets/toggles them should do the trick._ Can you add an example?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR 0) see obsolescence note; 1)`%toggle`,`your_command`,`%toggle`; 2) this means to replace those functions with wrappers around them; an example is beyond the scope of the answer, this should be clear to anyone with decent expertize.

Answer (score 10):

I think I finally figure this out. This method not really 'prevent' the ipython to record history but actually **delete** the history record. But I think still it is a good way to achieve this goal.

ipython history is stored in a **sqlite database** file in  `$(ipython locate)/profile_default/history.sqlite`.

The database table **History** has four columns: **session**, **line**, **source** and **source_raw**.  The **session** column presents for the `session_id` of current session, it can be get with the method in ipython:  `get_ipython().history_manager.hisdb.get_last_session_id()` in `ipython`.  The **line** column is just the line num.

So what I'm going to do is I'm going to **delete** this record in the database within `ipython` enviroment:

1) The history db object can be get  using `get_ipython().history_manager.db` in `ipython`

```
hismgr = get_ipython().history_manager
```

2) get the session id:

```
session_id = hismgr.get_last_session_id()
```

3) delete the history line with the `line_id` (assume it is 111 here) and `session_id`

```
hismgr.db.execute('DELETE FROM history WHERE line={0} and session={1}'.format(111, session_id))
```

4) the `In` and `Out` Array List is also kind like history, but it stored in memory, so it could be sweep or rewrite like variable.

```
In[111]=Out[111]=''
```

To 'prevent a command from being saved to ipython history', means delete the line's **history** record in database and and rewrite **In** and **Out** Array in ipython enviroment. And we could combine these four lines into to one to do the job one time for all. **Here is an example** if we want to delete line 128:

```
In [127]: history -l 3 -n
 124: history -l 3 -n
 125: hismgr = get_ipython().history_manager; session_id = hismgr.get_last_session_id();hismgr.db.execute('DELETE FROM history WHERE line={0} and session={1}'.format(123, session_id))
 126: history -l 3 -n

In [128]: passwd='123456'

In [129]: hismgr = get_ipython().history_manager; session_id = hismgr.get_last_session_id();hismgr.db.execute('DELETE FROM history WHERE line={0} and session={1}'.format(128, session_id));In[128]=Out[128]='';
Out[129]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x7f8dce3dae30>

In [130]: history -l 3 -n
 126: history -l 3 -n
 127: history -l 3 -n
 129: hismgr = get_ipython().history_manager; session_id = hismgr.get_last_session_id();hismgr.db.execute('DELETE FROM history WHERE line={0} and session={1}'.format(128, session_id));In[128]=Out[128]='';
```

The history line 128 is gone.

Here is some documents I went through

[IPython.core.history.HistoryManager](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.history.html?highlight=history%20manager#IPython.core.history.HistoryManager)

[python-sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)

Comment: This doesn't really "avoid storing a line in history", it rather deletes it from history post factum.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I know. But I read through the ipython document,  and can't  find some way really "prevent a command saved into history", So I come out that if I delete the line would do the same job.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution myself and then realized that I could just `input` the secret. E.g., I used the below to initialize github API when using pygithub:

```
In [1]: gh = github.Github(base_url="https://api.github.com", login_or_token=input("token: "))
token: abcd

In [2]: %hist
gh = github.Github(base_url="https://api.github.com", login_or_token=input("token: "))
%hist
```