# How can I make ipython incognito for a session?

Tags: python, ipython

Is there any way to force *IPython* not to save the current session's history to the history file? [A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093576/how-can-i-avoid-storing-a-command-in-ipython-history) has been asked about not saving a single command, but it's not practical to do that individually for every command in a session.

Answer (score 2):

The [`HistoryManager.enabled`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html#configtrait-HistoryManager.enabled) setting enables or disables history management. You can set it to False on the command line to disable history for that session:

```
ipython --HistoryManager.enabled=False
```

Alternatively, to maintain history in memory only, without saving to a history file, you can set `HistoryManager.hist_file=:memory:`

```
ipython --HistoryManager.hist_file=:memory:
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but yours has a limitation that I mentioned in my own!

Comment: My own answer has an issue too. Is there a way to disable writing history to the file while still having access to previous sessions' histories?

Comment: @MaskedMan: Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

[@user2357112 answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75238614/4935567) although is very useful has an issue: running *IPython* that way won't let you use your history at all! E.g. you can't search and use what you did before like declaring a function! So I find an approach that offers best of both worlds. You can access other sessions' histories and the current one won't save it in DB, just run this as the first command in your session:

```py
get_ipython().history_manager.enabled = False
```